# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module '../../temp'

Tags: javascript, node.js

My *Node.js* app is throwing the error below:_

```
C:\Users\vinod\server>npm start

> server@1.0.0 start C:\Users\vinod\server
> nodemon expGqlServer.js

[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node expGqlServer.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../temp'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\vinod\server\resolvers\post.js
- C:\Users\vinod\server\node_modules\@graphql-toolkit\file-loading\index.cjs.js
- C:\Users\vinod\server\node_modules\merge-graphql-schemas\index.cjs.js
- C:\Users\vinod\server\expGqlServer.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vinod\server\resolvers\post.js:2:14)
   
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\vinod\\server\\resolvers\\post.js',
    'C:\\Users\\vinod\\server\\node_modules\\@graphql-toolkit\\file-loading\\index.cjs.js',
    'C:\\Users\\vinod\\server\\node_modules\\merge-graphql-schemas\\index.cjs.js',
    'C:\\Users\\vinod\\server\\expGqlServer.js'
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I tried deleting and re-installing the `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` file, but with no result.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to S/O, can you share the code that caused this error, so we can help you?

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem. Try this:

```
npm install request
```

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, my program was referring to a temp folder in the current directory, but the path was incorrect.
ie
**const{posts}=require('../../temp');**
I changed it to
**const{posts}=require('../temp');**

Comment: This happened because I changed the file directory of the server, and some changes were made automatically by node.js

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue by adding .env file and setting up env(environental) variable cloned project from github and was using dotenv which all adds in gitignore so we gets missed most of the time

Comment: if you have cloned or woking on someone else project then this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I got faced the same issue and I solved it finally.
In my case I was performing `git push heroku main` which also `main` isn't the default branch.
I had to go to master branch first(default branch), merge the code with my other branch and then `heroku git:remote -a <repoName>` and `git push heroku master`.

HOPE this can help!